# Why does not my Xamarin.Forms iOS simulator run anymore? When I run the debugger it shuts down after 3-5 seconds

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Been working with a project for a week, no issues, when I did some minor changes to the code, suddenly the simulator does not run. Any idea what this can be?

What I changed codewise was just adding some dictionary with strings and changing the values on different pins on the map.

```
Dictionary<string,string> data = new Dictionary<string,string>();
..

Dictionary<string,string> myData = (Dictionary<string,string>) pin.BindingContext;
```

etc.

What is the issue? I get no error or something like that, the simulator just dies after 3-5 seconds. And it is very strange as it has been working flawlessy for 2 weeks and now after adding a few lines of codes it just dies. All of my other projects runs so it is just with this particular project I have this problem.

Could a "Rebuild all" be the simple solution?

Comment: As you mentioned, have you tried rebuilding? Possibly resetting the simulator?

Comment: cleaning the mtbs folder on the mac can also help. It's the xamarin build cache. It's located (hidden) here `/Users/<user>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/`. You can delete the complete folder. The buildserver will restore it on the next build.

Comment: tried both. still not working... ok sven, i will try it give me a sec

Comment: I only have two folders in my Xamarin folder. Components and ComponentInfo

Comment: Same thing when I deploy it to my iOS phone. turns black and goes back to the menu. Why does these mysterious things  keep happening in Xamarin for no reason?

Comment: Try opening the simulator, then go to Debug -> Open System Log... and now run the app and see if that gives you any info.

Comment: I found alot of:
  `/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator` and basically alot of blocks that ends with  `mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator`

Comment: `Mar 31 15:54:16 Johns-MacBook-Pro ProjectOne.iOS[1525]: Xamarin.iOS: Socket error while connecting to IDE on 105.0.0.1:63119: Connection refused`

Comment: `Mar 31 16:02:09 Johns-MacBook-Pro searchd[1220]: tcp_connection_destination_handle_tls_close_notify 15 closing socket due to TLS CLOSE_NOTIFY alert`

Comment: do u have auto update on? ,accidentally u updated something ? , if yes , try reinstalling the setup .
also check the ram usages , through activity monitor , are u running out of ram ? .
u can check profiler for possible memory leak (though won't happen in 3-4 sec)